# Como cambiar el texto de una etiqueta "<span>" en html al clonar un elemento con jquery y afectar solo al formulario o al elemento clonado

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo un formulario a dos pestañas con bootstrap y jquery, dicho formulario tiene un boton que permite clonar el div, el detalle es que ese formulario tiene un titulo que debe cambiar dinamicamente al agregar uno nuevo, y lo hace pero también cambia al padre o al formulario inicial y ese necesito que se mantenga incolume les muestro lo realizado hasta ahora.

Adicionalmente el acceder a los elementos desde el arreglo que se forma en json es un punto que me representa una duda.

```
$('#deleteRow').closest('.form-group').hide();

$('#addRow').on('click', function (e) {
    var len = $('.child-border').length + 1;
    var head = len + 1;
    $('#cabecera').text("Beneficiario Final N°" + head); 
    $('.parent-border').clone().find(':input').each(function (idx, ele) {
        ele.name = ele.name + len;
        ele.id = ele.id + len;
        ele.value = '';
    }).end().find('.form-group').toggle(true).end()
            .toggleClass('parent-border child-border').hide()
            .appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow');
});

$('button.btn:contains("Save")').on('click', function (e) {
    var jsonData = $('form.form-horizontal')
            .find(':input:not(button)').get()
            .reduce(function (acc, ele) {
                acc[ele.name || ele.id] = ele.value;
                return acc;
            }, {});
});

$('#container').on('click', '[id^=deleteRow]', function(e) {
    var jsonData = $(this).closest('.child-border, .parent-border')
            .find(':input:not(button)').get()
            .reduce(function (acc, ele) {
                acc[ele.name || ele.id] = ele.value;
                return acc;
            }, {});
    $(this).closest('.child-border, .parent-border').remove();
});
```

y en html

```html
<div class="container">
         <div class="starter-template">
            <br /><br />
            <h2 class="salto_linea"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Certificación de Beneficiarios Finales <br /></h2>
            <div class="progress">
               <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $_SESSION['barra_especifica']; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?php echo $_SESSION['barra_especifica']; ?>%;">
                  <?php echo $_SESSION['barra_especifica']; ?>% completado
               </div>
            </div>
            <div id="carga">
               <img src="images/spin.svg">
               <p class="text-center">Actualizando...</p>
            </div>
            <?php 
               $id_cliente = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];   

               $consulta_bf = "SELECT pa_usuario_adic, pa_acciones, cl_pn_nombre1, cl_pn_nombre2, cl_pn_apellido1, cl_pn_apellido2,  cl_nj_id_identificacion1, cl_nj_numero_identificacion1, cl_pn_f_nacimiento, cl_pn_id_nacionalidad, cl_nj_correo_prin FROM personas_adicionales, clientes 
                           WHERE pa_id_cliente = '$id_cliente' 
                           AND pa_tipo_per = 'BF'
                           AND cl_id_usuario = pa_usuario_adic";

               $resultado_bf = basedatos($consulta_bf);
               $cantidad = mysql_num_rows($resultado_bf);
               $id_bf = array(); 
               $por_part = array(); 
               $nombres = array();
               $apellidos = array();
               $tipo_id = array();
               $num_id = array();
               $fec_nac = array();
               $pais_nac = array();
               $mail_bf = array();
               $s = array();

               $i=0;  

               while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado_bf)) {
                 $id_bf[$i] = $fila['pa_usuario_adic'];
                 $por_part[$i] = $fila['pa_acciones'];
                 $nombres[$i] = utf8_encode($fila['cl_pn_nombre1'].' '.$fila['cl_pn_nombre2']);
                 $apellidos[$i] = utf8_encode($fila['cl_pn_apellido1'].' '.$fila['cl_pn_apellido2']);
                 $tipo_id[$i] = $fila['cl_nj_id_identificacion1'];
                 $num_id[$i] = $fila['cl_nj_numero_identificacion1'];
                 $fec_nac[$i] = $fila['cl_pn_f_nacimiento'];
                 $pais_nac[$i] = $fila['cl_pn_id_nacionalidad'];
                 $mail_bf[$i] = $fila['cl_nj_correo_prin'];

                 $d = '-';
                 $e = '/';

                 $fec_nac[$i] = str_replace($d, $e, $fec_nac[$i]);

                 $s[$i] = substr($fec_nac[$i] , 8 , 2) . '/' . substr($fec_nac[$i] , 5 , 2) . '/' . substr($fec_nac[$i] , 0 , 4);

                 if ($tipo_id[$i] == 78) {
                   $cedula_tipo[$i] = substr($num_id[$i], 0, 1);
                   $num_id_fin[$i] = substr($num_id[$i], 1);
                 }else{
                   $cedula_tipo[$i] = "";
                   $num_id_fin[$i] = $num_id[$i];
                 }

                 $int_coma = strpos($tipo_id[$i], ',');
                 if ($int_coma != 0) 
                 {                
                   $str_identificacion = $tipo_id[$i];
                   $tipo_id[$i] = substr($tipo_id[$i] , 0 , $int_coma);

                   if ($tipo_id[$i] === '160')
                   {
                     $des_documento[$i] = substr($str_identificacion , $int_coma + 1 , strlen($str_identificacion));
                   }
                 }

                 $i++;
               }

               $consulta_pc = "SELECT pa_nombre, pa_apellido, pa_fecha_nac,  pa_tipo_id, pa_num_id, pa_nacionalidad FROM personas_adicionales WHERE pa_id_cliente ='$id_cliente' AND pa_tipo_per = 'PC'";

               $resultadopc = basedatos($consulta_pc);
               $row = mysql_fetch_array($resultadopc);

               $nombrepc = $row['pa_nombre'];
               $apellidopc = $row['pa_apellido'];
               $nombrespc = $nombrepc.' '.$apellidopc;
               $fec_nacpc = $row['pa_fecha_nac'];
               $tipo_id_pc = $row['pa_tipo_id'];
               $int_comapc = strpos($tipo_id_pc, ',');  

               if ($int_comapc != 0){

                 $tipo_id_comp_pc = $tipo_id_pc; 
                 $tipo_id_pc = substr($tipo_id_pc, 0 , $int_comapc);
                 $des_od_pc = substr($tipo_id_comp_pc , $int_comapc + 1 , strlen($tipo_id_comp_pc));

               }   

               $num_id_pc = $row['pa_num_id'];
               $pais_nac_pc = $row['pa_nacionalidad'];

               $conslta_dir_pc = "SELECT di_desc_direccion FROM direcciones WHERE di_id_cliente = $id_cliente AND di_id_tipo_direccion = '333'";
               $resultadodirpc = basedatos($conslta_dir_pc);
               $rowdir = mysql_fetch_array($resultadodirpc);

               $direccionpc = $rowdir['di_desc_direccion'];

               $d = '-';
               $e = '/';

               $fec_nacpc = str_replace($d, $e, $fec_nacpc);

               $z = substr($fec_nacpc , 8 , 2) . '/' . substr($fec_nacpc , 5 , 2) . '/' . substr($fec_nacpc , 0 , 4);


               if ($tipo_id_pc == 78) {
                 $cedula_tipo_pc = substr($num_id_pc, 0, 1);
                 $numero_identificacion_pc_fin = substr($num_id_pc, 1);
               }else{
                 $cedula_tipo_pc = "";
                 $numero_identificacion_pc_fin = $num_id_pc;
               }

               $int_comapc = strpos($tipo_idpc, ',');  

               if ($int_comapc != 0){

                   $tipo_id_pc = substr($tipo_idpc , 0 , $int_comapc);
                   $des_od_pc = substr($tipo_idpc , $int_comapc + 1 , strlen($tipo_idpc));
               }   
               ?>

            <div class="row tabs-container">
               <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                     <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab">Beneficiarios Finales</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab">Persona de Control</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                     <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1default">
                           <!--<div id="add_firmante" class="text-right">
                              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="add"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> </button>
                           </div>-->
                           <form id="surveyForm" method="POST" action="" name="surveyForm" id="surveyForm" class="form-horizontal">

                              <!-- Beneficiario Final
                                 ========================================================-->
                              <div class="parent-border">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-10">
                                            <button type="button" id="deleteRow" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-lg"><i
                                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>   
                              <div class="panel panel-default" id="uno">
                                 <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title text-left">
                                       <span id="cabecera"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"><i class="fa fa-user">Benefiario Final N° 1</i></a></span>
                                    </h4>
                                 </div>
                                 <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                    <div class="panel-body">

                                       <div class="form-group">
                                          <label>
                                             <h3>Identificación del Beneficiario</h3>
                                          </label>
                                          <!--<div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Correo Electronico del Beneficiario</label>
                                             <div class="col-xs-8">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Correo</span>
                                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mail_bf1" id="mail_bf1" value="<?php echo $mail_bf[0] ?>" />
                                                   <input type="hidden" name="id_bf1" id="id_bf1" value="<?php echo $id_bf[0] ?>">
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>-->
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Nombres y Apellidos</label>
                                             <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Nombres</span>
                                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombres1" id="nombres1"  value="<?php echo $nombres[0] ?>" />
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Apellidos</span>
                                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos1" id="apellidos1"  value="<?php echo $apellidos[0] ?>"/>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Documento de identificación</label>
                                             <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Tipo</span>
                                                   <select class="form-control" name="tipo_id1" id="tipo_id1"  >
                                                      <option value="" default selected>Tipo de documento</option>
                                                      <?php 
                                                         $consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM catalogo WHERE ct_id_tabla = '4'";
                                                         $resultado2 = basedatos($consulta2);
                                                         while ($fila2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado2)) {
                                                          $cat = $fila2['ct_id_cat'];
                                                           ?>
                                                      <option value="<?php echo $fila2['ct_id_cat']; ?>" <?php if($cat == $tipo_id[0]){ echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo utf8_encode($fila2['ct_descripcion']) ?></option>
                                                      <?php } ?>
                                                   </select>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">No.</span>
                                                   <span class="input-group-btn" id="a">
                                                      <select class="btn" id="cedula_tipo1" name="cedula_tipo1" disabled >
                                                         <option value="" default selected>...</option>
                                                         <option <?php if($cedula_tipo[0] == 'V'){echo "selected = 'selected'";} ?>>V</option>
                                                         <option <?php if($cedula_tipo[0] == 'E'){echo "selected = 'selected'";} ?>>E</option>
                                                      </select>
                                                   </span>
                                                   <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="num_id1" id="num_id1" value="<?php echo $num_id_fin[0] ?>" />
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group" id="lbl_otro_documento_1">
                                             <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Especifique:</label>                            
                                             <div class="col-xs-4">                 
                                                <input type="text" maxlength="20" name="otro_documento_1" id="otro_documento_1" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($des_documento[0]) ?>" class="form-control" >
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                                             <div class="col-xs-8">
                                                <div class="input-group input-append date" id="datePicker">
                                                   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Fecha de nacimiento</span>
                                                   <input type="text" data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy"  id="s1" name="s1" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento" value="<?php if($fec_nac[0] != NULL) {echo $s[0];} ?>" />
                                                   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="col-xs-2 control-label"></label>
                                             <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">País de nacimiento</span>
                                                   <select class="form-control" name="pais_nacimiento1" id="pais_nacimiento1" >
                                                      <option value="" default selected>País de nacimiento</option>
                                                      <?php 
                                                         $consulta = "SELECT pa_id_pais, pa_descripcion FROM paises ORDER BY pa_descripcion";
                                                         $resultado = basedatos($consulta);
                                                         while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) { ?>
                                                      <option value="<?php echo $fila['pa_id_pais']; ?>" <?php if($fila['pa_id_pais']== $pais_nac[0]){ echo "selected='selected'";} ?> ><?php echo utf8_encode($fila['pa_descripcion']) ?></option>
                                                      <?php } ?>
                                                   </select>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">% Participación</span>
                                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="4" onkeyup="sumarPART();" name="por_part1" id="por_part1" value="<?php echo $por_part[0] ?>" />
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Dirección</label>
                                             <div class="col-xs-8">
                                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="direccion1" name="direccion1" ><?php echo $direccion[0] ?></textarea>        
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--<div class="form-group">
                                       <label class="control-label col-xs-3"></label>
                                         <div class="col-xs-offset-9 col-xs-8">
                                           <div class="input-group" align="right"> 
                                               <input type="button" id="consultar"  name="consultar" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Consultar" onclick="realizaConsulta(1);" >
                                         </div>   
                                       </div>
                                       </div>-->
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div id="container">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-6">
                                        <button type="button" id="addRow" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-lg"><i
                                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                           </form>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Persona Control
                           ========================================================-->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2default">
                           <form id="surveyForm" method="POST" action="" name="surveyForm" id="surveyForm" class="form-horizontal">
                              <div class="panel panel-default" id="pc">
                                 <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title text-left">
                                       <a  data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="false">Persona de Control</a>
                                    </h4>
                                 </div>
                                 <div  role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSeven">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                       <?php include "bloque7_pc_ab.php"; ?>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <br /><br /><br />
                              <br /><br />
                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-9">
                                    <!--<input type="hidden" value="V" name="valida">-->
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="guardar" name="guardar" value="Guardar">
                                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="registro_ab_j.php" role="button">Regresar sin guardar</a>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </form>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

El tema es afectar solo al código que salga despues de clonar sin afectar al padre